# Why i am getting undefined in jquery when trying to get data from value returned from asp.net web service?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

// Web service Code webService.asmx
this is code to get data from web service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET     AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

public WebService()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getTableData()
{

    SqlConnection _connect = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        _connect.ConnectionString =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPV2ConnectionString"].ToString();
        _connect.Open();

        string query = "Select FirstName [Name], EmpCode [Code] From payroll.tblEmpMaster where EmpNo between 12 And 15";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _connect);
        string strquery = null;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        _connect.Close();
        strquery = DataSetToJSON(ds);

        return strquery;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _connect.Close();
        throw ex;
    }

}

public string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
{

    StringBuilder JsonString = new StringBuilder();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    //Exception Handling
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        JsonString.Append("[ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            JsonString.Append("{ ");
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    JsonString.Append("\"" + dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() +
                          "\":" + "\"" +
                          dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
                }
                else if (j == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    JsonString.Append("\"" +
                       dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" +
                       "\"" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
                }
            }

            /*end Of String*/
            if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                JsonString.Append("} ");
            }
            else
            {
                JsonString.Append("}, ");
            }
        }
        JsonString.Append("]");

        return JsonString.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }


}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {

            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{null}",
                url: "WebService.asmx/getTableData",
                dataTyp: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    var xml = $(data);

                    $("#table1").append("<tr><th>name</th><th>code</th></tr>");
                    $.each(xml, function (i, v) {
                        //                        $('#p1').html(v.city);

                        $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + v.name + "</td>  <td>" + v.code + "</td></tr>");
                    });

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });

        });
    });


</script>
```

Send

What am i doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

try using `data.d`

```
 success: function (data) {
   var xml = data.d;
   alert(xml);
}
```

---

```
 public class UserInfo
{
        public string Name;
        public string Code;
        public string Salary;
}


[WebMethod]
public List<UserInfo> getTableData()
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    List<UserInfo> UserInfo = new List<UserInfo>();
 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "ProcedureName";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                    string Code = dr["Code"].ToString();
                    string makingyear = dr["carYear"].ToString();
                     UserInfo.Add(new usr {Name = Name, Code = Code });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return UserInfo;
}
```

---

```
$("#button").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         data: "{null}",
        url: "WebService.asmx/getTableData",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
   
    function OnSuccess(response) {
      console.log(response.d)
    }
    function OnErrorCall(response) { console.log(error); }
    });
```

Comment: @Teerath: debug and check the response on your webmethod

Comment: I tried using  
success: function (data) {
   var xml = $(data);
   alert(xml);
}
It gives output as:
[{ "Name": "SANJAY", "Code": "01" }, { "Name": "RAMESH", "Code": "02" }, { "Name": "A.", "Code": "03" }, { "Name": "KOSHALENDRA", "Code": "04"}] 
but i am not able to access value;
And when i use
success: function (data) {
   var xml = $(data.d);
   alert(xml);
}
It gives nothing

Comment: @Teerath: just  `alert(data.d);` and check

Comment: It gives nothing. i am beginner to jquery. can you please tell me where we use .d property . I am not able to access this property.

Answer (score 0):

Two snippits of interest from your code:

```
return JsonString.ToString();
```

and

```
var xml = $(data);
```

These are trying to do different things. The web service is returning JSON data, but you are trying to parse it as XML data. You need to parse the server output as JSON data:

```
var xml = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Now you can go in and inspect the object to see what you will need to iterate to get the result you want. On Chrome you can use the console to inspect easily:

```
console.log("xml: %o", xml);
```